# Unable to find element on closed window in Python using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, protected-mode

```
def check_text(browser, sitename):

    browser.get(sitename)

    try:
        text = browser.find_element_by_class_name("text_content").text

        if "foo" in text:
            print("ok")

        else:
            print("not ok")

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("no such elem")


def check_internet_explorer():

    sitename="*foo site*"
    caps = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER
    caps['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True
    ie = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=caps)
    check_text(ie, sitename)
```

This code works just fine on windows 10. When I try to run it on windows 7, the webpage loads but I get this error: "Unable to find element on closed window"
I looked for this error online and it's something about internet explorer protected mode. I tried adding the "ignore protect mode settings" capability, but I get the same error. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

When you work with **`Selenium 3.4.0`**, **`IEDriverServer 3.4.0`** with **`IE(v 10/11)`** the error: **"Unable to find element on closed window"** may occur due to several limitations of **`Internet Explorer`** and the **`IEDriverServer.exe`**. To prevent those errors we can explicitly set the `nativeEvents` and `requireWindowFocus` to `true` through the `DesiredCapabilities` class as follows:

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER
caps['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True
caps['nativeEvents'] = True
caps['ignoreZoomSetting'] = True
caps['requireWindowFocus'] = True
caps['InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS'] = True
ie = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=caps)
```

> As you are facing issue on **`Windows 7`** the documentation mentions the following points: On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the **Protected Mode** settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the **Protected Mode** settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled **"Enable Protected Mode"**.

You can find more documentation about these facts in this [**link**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver).

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Unfortunately, the exact same error appears, after I tried what you said.

Comment: Is your `Zoom Level` set to 100% ? Selenium, IEDriverServer & IE version please. Thanks

Comment: Yes, zoom level is set to 100%. IE version: 11.0.9600.17843 (IE 11). Selenium version: 3.4.3. IE webdriver version: 3.4.0.0

Comment: @cosminp Did you get a chance to cross check the settings mentioned in the link I provided in my Answer? Thanks

Comment: I tried every possible arangement between those 5 settings (including the last one, with flakiness) and it's still the same result.

Comment: Can you please confirm the Protected Mode settings once? Thanks

Comment: I confrimed the Protected Mode settings and the same error appeared. After that, I confirmed the intranet settings and I get the same error.

Comment: Can you switchover to `32-bit IEDriverServer.exe` even if your IE (11) remains 64-bit? Update me the status please. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the URL if it is a public one? Thanks

Comment: In my path (C:\Python36\selenium\webdrivers), I replaced the 64 bit IE webdriver with the 32 bit one. The error is still there, unfortunately.